# Create a Link to a Custom ASP.NET Site in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, asp.net, iis, wspbuilder

I created a custom ASP.NET site and published it to our SharePoint server.  All I want is to have a link available in our SharePoint 2010 intranet site to this ASP.NET site.  What is the best way to do this, and how do I do this?  Do I need to create a new site in IIS (we have IIS v6 on Windows Server 2008 R2)?  Can I use the existing SharePoint IIS?  Can I do this through the Central Administration Console?

I have tried using WSPBuilder and deploying it to the server, but my development server is not the same as the actual SharePoint server, and I couldn't find any config to connect it to the actual server, so that didn't work.  I tried a Page Viewer web part but the ASP.NET site always returns a 404 or 500 error code.  The end goal is very simple, getting there however is proving very difficult.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like your problem has nothing to do with SharePoint. Your custom web site is broken.

Comment: testing the site in visual studio runs perfectly - it's only when implementing it through SharePoint or trying to get it to work through IIS.  I'm exploring other options such as creating a webpart with similar functionality found in my asp.net site.

Comment: forget about SharePoint for the moment and try to get your web site working in IIS in its own site on the server.  Once it's working you can then link it up to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

if its only a link that you want on the intranet, does it matter where it is located? how about on quick links on the left side?

**Add, edit or delete a Quick Launch heading on a non-publishing site**

> 1.On the **Site actions** menu , click **Site settings**.
>
> 2.In the **Look and Feel** section, click **Quick launch**.
>
> Note   The Quick launch command appears under Look and Feel only if
>   the publishing features are not enabled for your site and you have at
>   least the permissions obtained by being added to the default Designers
>   SharePoint group for the site.
>
> 3.Do one of the following:
>
> To add a new heading, click **New Heading**, type the URL and a
>   description for the heading, and then **click OK**.
>
> **> The URL can link to any valid path, such as a folder within this site,
>   a share within your organization’s intranet, or a link to a location
>   on the internet. URL is optional for headings.**
>
> To edit a heading, click the Edit button  next to the heading. Make
>   any necessary changes to the URL and description, and then click OK.
>
> To delete a heading, click the Edit button  next to the heading, click
>   Delete, and then click OK.
>
> Important    When you delete a heading from the Quick Launch on a
>   non-publishing site, any links contained under that heading are also
>   deleted.

this is an easy option if that is what your looking for! for a detailed walk through follow this link! the above was take from the link! goto the heading in bold:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/configure-the-quick-launch-for-site-navigation-HA102130960.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately I need to create the IIS virtual directory for this, and every time I did that there was always some SharePoint permission or session state block that prevented me from viewing the site.  It really doesn't matter where the link goes (Quick Launch could be a good option), but the problem is with my ASPX pages stored on my SharePoint server.  I'm not sure what the best option is, but I've gone a different route and created a webpart with similar functionality.  Luckily I still had the code, but I'm still looking for a good solution to this problem.  Thanks